The commutativity of the subgroups of the group generated by two elements with special relation
This is from the exercise 8.2 of Basic Algebra by Jacobson:

I slightly strengthened the assumptions:
Let $G$ be a group with two generators $x,y$ such that
$$x^u=y^v=e,\quad y^{-1}xy=x^m\quad\text{with}\quad u=p^m,\quad v=p^r,$$where $p$ is a prime. Assume moreover that the orders of $x$ and $y$ are respectively $u$ and $v$ (or equivalently: the order of $G$ is $uv$).
It is known that $y^{-1}x^iy=(y^{-1}xy)^i=x^{mi}$, then $y^{-j}x^iy^j=x^{im^j}$.
Now let $i=1$, $j=v$, then it turns into $x=x^{m^v}$, so $$m^v\equiv1\pmod u.$$
Now the question is to
prove that for arbitrary subgroups $H$, $K$ of $G$,$$HK=KH.$$
I only find that $\langle x\rangle$ is normal.

It is from the exercises of 8.2  of Basic Algebra by Jacobson.

Thanks for your edit.I tried to prove it in a special case and gernalize it because I think they are equivalent.But it may cause some unnecessary trouble.Do you have any ideas now?

They are not equivalent and yours, though weaker, is less clear. Again: I have no idea about the answer, and the post might be improved by adding some "context": some more thoughts and efforts to solve it. All these comment are obsolete. I shall delete mine.
